# How is degrees of freedom connected with the number of samples?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

So this question gets asked every other week "why do we divide by n - 1", but I'm trying to understand it from a different perspective. I know why we divide by "n - 1" for sample variance, and it's pretty simple to prove algebraically [example proof](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/01/11/bessel/)

From this viewpoint, it's very clear that there needs to be a correction of n-1. Fine.

What I don't really understand, is the connection with degrees of freedom and why we divide by degrees of freedom n-k rather than n (which seems to be more of a linear algebra topic?).

One theory I have that is connected with the random vector [X_1, X_2, ..., X_n] is that if we only have n-1 degrees of freedoms, we have one random variable that is a "constant" (and therefore non-existing in the form as a random variable). If every random variable is a dimension, we lose one dimension in this case as that variable is just a locked in number.

Because the estimated mean for a low number of samples is probably not the same as the real mean, this value we have left will be dependent on the other variables and it will most likely be close to the sample mean. This also suggests that it will be a pretty small number and it won't add "enough" and hence an underestimation.

This is probably not the whole truth and a lot of handwaving, so if someone could help me understand this better (maybe from a Linear Algebra perspective?) I'd be grateful

Comment: In your  $[X_1, X_2, ..., X_n]$ example, I feel it is more that in a sense you treat $\bar X =\frac1n \sum\limits_1^n X_n$ as given in some sense so restricting the values to a subspace where you might say $X_n$ is determined by $X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}$.  Similarly with a chi-square test, in a sense you treat the marginal sums as given, so reducing the degrees of freedom from $nk$ to $(n-1)(k-1)$.  This does not fully justify the adjustments - they still need to be demonstrated analytically.

Answer (score 1):

The degrees of freedom simply signify the dimension of the vector space of the sample. When samples come from continuous distribution, the probability of linear dependency is zero. However, many statistics, even though they are a function of a random vector $(X_1, \ldots, X_n),$ which *a priori* has $n$ degrees of freedom, will typically need to be adjusted depending on the restrictions imposed on the sample. In the example of the mean, the restriction is that the mean vector is always orthogonal to the main diagonal $\mathbf{1}.$

More explicitly, suppose that we now have a sample of observations $(x_1, \ldots, x_n),$ this sample lives in the $n$-space and therefore has $n$ degrees of freedom (i.e., the direction to which it can move, provided is not a corner point, spans $n$ independent vectors). If we now centralise it, so that we consider $(x_1 - \bar x, \ldots, x_n - \bar x),$ we are essentially projecting this sample from $n$ space to a $(n-1)$ subspace, namely, the subspace engendred by $\mathbf{1} = (1, \ldots, 1).$ Indeed, if we take the dot product
$$
(x_1 - \bar x, \ldots, x_n - \bar x) \cdot \mathbf{1} = \sum x_i - n \bar x = 0,
$$
we see that the centralised sample (a.k.a. "deviatio scores") is always orthogonal to the main diagonal. Thus, the deviation scores no longer have $n$ degrees of freedom but $n-1.$ If you further impose other restriction, you further need to reduce the degrees of freedom.

For example, when we have a contingency table with fixed row totals, we have $I$ rows (random vectors) with $J$ variables in each. But the row totals being fixed signify $\sum_j x_{i,j} = n_{i+}$ are constants. This equation defines a linear variety of dimension $J-1$ in the $IJ$-space (we are thinking of the whole table $(x_{i,j})$ as an $IJ$-vector), which is where the $i$th row lives. Typically, the grand total is also known (which follows from knowing each row total, so you also know $n_{++} = \sum_i n_{i+}$). In this case, we have a linear dependency between all equations $\sum_j x_{i,j} = n_{i+}$ ($i = 1, \ldots, n$), as the last equation is a linear combination of the previous $I - 1.$ As a consequence, from the original $IJ$ random variables (that have $IJ$ degrees of freedom) we have imposed restrictions on them so they now are restricted to live in a $(I-1)(J-1)$-subspace of the original $IJ$-space. In this case, any statistic arising from the table have only $(I-1)(J-1)$ degrees of freedom (such as the classic $G^2$ or Pearson asymptotic statistics).

In the linear regression (and GLM, Wilk's theorem, etc), this continues to happen. In a nutshell, and with birds eye's view, we are restricting the $n$ random variables to live in a subspace of dimension $k$ and therefore we have $k$ degrees of freedom (equivalently, we imposed $n-k$ linearly independent restrictions each of which kills one degree of freedom).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, so I get the reason from a Linear Algebra perspective why we lose one dimension as the main diagonal acts like a normal vector of that subspace. I still can't connect this to why we use the dimensions (degrees of freedom) for dividing f.e variance. Note as mentioned, I do understand it from other perspectives mentioned in the post, but not from this one

Comment: The degrees of freedom essentially are the number of "true independent" random variables in the sample. We know that variance is linear in this number, so dividing by it recovers the variance of a single random variable.